# How to write a script jquery accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Good afternoon

It is necessary for the block Question-answer to write a script on jquery by type accordion

Block `html` (such blocks will be repeated):

```
<div class="question">
    <h3 class="question__title">Что влияет на стоимость услуг?</h3>
    <div class="question__icon"></div>
    <div class="question__wr">
        <p class="question__text text">Стоимость услуг зависят от нескольких факторов:</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How it should work:

By clicking on `question__title`  to the tag `question` the `question--open` tag is added and the block unfolds, at the same time the previous block is collapsed.

Here is my script, but it does not work correctly, it deploys all the blocks at once

```
$(".question__title").click(function() {
    $(".question").addClass("question--open");
    $(".question__title").click(function() {
        $(".question").removeClass("question--open");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Please tell me how to write a script correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: why not using jquery ui accordion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  just need to add the `question--open` class to the clicked element to expand it and to collapse all of the other tags you need to remove this class from them.

```
$(".question__title").click(function() {
     $(".question").not($(this).closest("div.question")).removeClass("question--open");
     $(this).closest("div.question").toggleClass("question--open");
});
```

The line `$(".question").removeClass("question--open");` is to remove the active class to collapsed them and

```
$(this).closest("div.question").addClass("question--open");
```

is to add the active class to the clicked element to make it expand.

Comment: This script works. Thanks for the help. How do I do that when I click on ** question__title ** the block also curled?

Comment: Sorry didn't get what you are saying ?

Comment: Now when you click on the active block again, it does not close.

Comment: Working. You really helped. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(".question__title").click(function() {
 $("question--open").removeClass("question--open");
        $(this).addClass("question--open");
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Does not work. .question--open should be added to the .question tag